# When using generics for both in and out types, why is out type generally last?

Tags: c#, generics

This is a bit of a subjective question I guess but I was hoping for opinions on either side of the argument.

So take this for example in C#:

```
public interface IFactory<Tin, Tout> : IFactory
{
    Tout Create(Tin param);
}
```

Now as you can see we take an input type and an output type, however a lot of frameworks often have a raft of different generics in these sort of cases where you often end up having `TinOne`, `TinTwo` etc to cope with multiple use cases. So even in the C# source it generally does `<all input types, output type>` however when you actually go to look at the implementations of interfaces like this, you generally (again subjective) want to know what the return type is, as that is often the contract you care about for the rest of the program, so it often makes it harder to find these interfaces in code due to the output type being last in the list not first.

So why was this approach taken? as personally I would find output being first being more logical, but I am sure there is a good reason why.

Comment: Hold on a sec, the interface implements itself?!

Comment: @kayess no, it implements a base non generic interface that overloads the name IFactory. Many library interfaces that predate generics have a deriving generic interface with the same name

Comment: Also for clearer reading you could make the first type argument contravariant using the `in` keyword and make the second covariant by using `out` keyword.

Comment: Ran out of edit time: also using in/out you cannot accidentally swap TIn/TOut since that would cause invalid variance by the compiler.

Comment: @kayess I don't think OP is talking about interfaces he is writing, but existing interfaces that he uses, that have invariant(or not) type parameters

Comment: To be honest I just made a simple use case, the point here is the order of the generics, not if they should be contra/covarient etc, as also although the question pertains to c# it is applicable in other languages so didnt want to put in too much c# specific stuff. The above code shows the underlying intent well enough and doesnt really need any other syntactic sprinkling to confuse things further, granted the base interface type is probably not needed.

Comment: Functions like `Array.Copy` having `source` before `destination` is far more annoying for me.

Comment: If they did it the (admitted subjective) way you wanted, then the question from someone else would be "Why is the out parameter first?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the way function types are normally written:

```
a → b
```

is a function that takes an `a` and returns a `b`.

```
(a, b) → c
```

is a function that takes a tuple of `(a, b)` and returns a `c`.

```
a → b → c
```

is a function that takes an `a` and returns a function that takes a `b` and returns a `c` (which is the curried version of the second function above).

In all these cases,  the inputs come first, then the output. And it makes sense: data flows from input to output, types flow from input to input to output, and we read from left to right.

It also matches with declarations for subroutine prototypes in many languages. E.g. Scala:

```
// method:
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int

// function:
(a: Int, b: Int) ⇒ { //body of the function, return type is inferred }
```

Go:

```
func add(a int, b int) int
```

Haskell:

```
add :: (Int, Int) → Int
-- or more idiomatically:
add :: Int → Int → Int
```

And so on.

Comment: maybe make a note that C is the odd-one-out with its `return_t name (param_t param...)` syntax and the .NET CLR supports multiple languages with differing declaration orders

Comment: It also feels related to the way the vast majority of things in computing with a source and a destination/target come in that order by default (screw microsoft symlink tool thing…); at least i see in/out as the same concept.